# Display Documentation From Function

Tags: documentation, searching

I would like a documentation function that works like that following.

```
doc["search terms"]
```

and it displays the list of search terms.

And then `doc["search terms",2]` displays the second result.
The important key here is that the printed out values and part of the print out.

**EDIT: So I  have added a bounty because I would like to do this without bringing up the window everytime.**

Comment: Something like this (incomplete)? ``doc = Import@Documentation`ResolveLink["Tab"];

Cases[doc, 
 TemplateBox[{Cell[TextData[name_]], link_}, 
   "SearchResultLink", ___] :> {name, link}, Infinity]``

Comment: @Szabolcs It appears calling you function with the name displays the actual page which isn't perfect but does work.  How do you recommend accounting for page numbers and distinguishing searching and displaying a page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to do this without having the documentation pop up for a second but this is the basic idea.

```
doc[i_] := (
   n = Documentation`HelpLookup[i]; nG = NotebookGet[n]; 
   NotebookClose[n]; 
   CellPrint@Replace[nG, Notebook[{x___}, y___] :> {x}]
   );
doc["Print"]
```

Comment: FYI this reliably crashes version 11.0.0 for me (Windows).

Comment: @chuy does the version Szabolics have in the comments above work?  `doc = Import@Documentation``ResolveLink["Tab"]; Cases[doc, TemplateBox[{Cell[TextData[name_]], link_}, "SearchResultLink", ___] :> {name, link}, Infinity]`

Comment: Yes it works (no crash)

Comment: Mathematica 11.0 crashes when `CellPrint` acts on the result of `Replace[nG, Notebook[{x___}, y___] :> {x}]`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Does the version I posted above as a comment work?

Comment: It works in the sense that it does not crash, but `doc["Print"]` produces a mass of low-level code having nothing to do with "Print".

Answer (score 3):

This should be a good starting point:

```
nb = Import@Documentation`ResolveLink["NSolve start:1"];

Cases[nb, Cell[___, "SearchResultCell", ___], Infinity]
```

There's no popup. `start:1` causes this to get the first page of search results (instead of going directly to the `NSolve` page).

In v10.1 or later, use

```
NotebookImport[ 
    Documentation`ResolveLink["NSolve start:1"],
    "SearchResultCell" 
]
```